# Visual studio/Dotnet DebuggerDisplay attribute, does it have more than "nq" switch?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debuggerdisplay

What switches are there to the [DebuggerDisplay attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx)?

I am aware of the `nq` switch that removes the quotation marks around the output.
Are there more?